# What exactly is JSON-RPC?

Tags: json-rpc

What exactly is JSON-RPC, and what is the relationship when used in text editors/IDE? How does the term server apply to it? I have read the Wikipedia article and was not clear to me. In a text editor/IDE that is not connected to the internet when is the term server has to do with JSON-RPC?

Comment: think of it as SOAP, but using json instead of xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly is JSON-RPC

It's a way for someone to send a request and receive a response. (On the other side of the same coin, it's a way for someone to receive a request and send a response)

> what is the relationship when used in text editors/IDE?

All complex pieces of software (including text editors and IDEs) are made of multiple components. JSON-RPC is one way for different components to communicate with each other. It is not the only way, though.

> How does the term server apply to it? ... In a text editor/IDE that is not connected to the internet when is the term server has to do with JSON-RPC?

From the [specification](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification):

```
The Client is defined as the origin of Request objects and the handler of Response objects. 
The Server is defined as the origin of Response objects and the handler of Request objects.
```

To paraphrase, a "Server" is simply someone who receives a Request. No internet required.